# How to build a desktop application with Flex 3 Builder

Tags: apache-flex, desktop-application

I recently got flex builder 3, and it seems to be a really cool IDE.
I am stuck at the point where I need to create desktop app.
Can someone here please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to answer the question, you can go to File->New Project .The IDE asks you for the name you want to give to your app,as well as down a few lines , you would see that there is an option to select the type of App, webapp or desktop.
That should do your work.

Please keep in mind , that the webapp, does not allow you many things, like native process invocation, multitouch gesture support on touch devices, and low level file handling.

Incase you are building an app that needs any of the above, you are better to go for Desktop app.Incase you want something that runs in a browser , you should go with a webapp.

Comment: can you point me to links which will help me understand what all things are possible with a desktop app?

Answer (score 0):

this should get you started.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=UsingFB_1.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use Adobe AIR to convert flash or flex to be desktop application.

http://www.adobe.com/products/air/

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to develop an Air Application. Check adobe site for getting started with Air application.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air.html